# How to take data from one model field to another in Django using fixture?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

I am using Django and i have two model:  Jobs and Tit_suggestion. Both of them are like this :

```
class title_suggestion(models.Model):
    functional_area = models.ForeignKey(Jobs)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class Jobs(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So , In Title_suggestion the field "job_title" contains data based on functional area id . and i have fixture file of this model.

Now i want to load same data in new field in jobs model using that fixture file. How to do this?? Please help me out. i am stuck here from last two days but could not find the relevant solution.

Comment: Tit suggestion?! What kind of website are you trying to make?

Comment: Can you at least fix the name of the class to be PEP8 compliant: `TitSuggesstion` After all, tits deserve some respect.

Comment: please don't stuck on name, please let me know about my problem solution.

Comment: actually it means title_suggestion , so dont take it wrong brother and help me if u can.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't use a fixture from your `title_suggestion` model to populate your `Jobs` model because the structure is different.

In the `title_suggestion` fixture, `job` will be specified as the integer representing the primary key of the related job, not a complete object in JSON format.

Instead, you need to create as many `Job` instances in your fixture for jobs, then match up any foreign key instances in the `title_suggestion` fixture.

Comment: Actually In the title_suggestion model, the job_title is based on the PK of name field in Jobs model.So i need to create same field in the Jobs model and want to store the data from Title_suggestion to Jobs for that particular field. and i have Fixture file of Title_suggestion model.

Comment: You can't do that from a fixture as far as I know. Fixtures have zero knowledge of relationships, and aren't able to query other models for information. They are just static files.